# insert comma separated list of ids in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that takes a comma separated list of ints and adds them to a table.

For this example, the table has 1 column. So the stored procedure would just take a string like '1,2,3' and insert 3 rows into the table.

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this. Do I have to write something to split the string and then manually loop through the ids? Can I do something like

```
insert into table values split(idsString)
```

and somehow do it in one statement instead of a manual loop?

Comment: Try this answer over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string

Comment: @AaronBertrand I like the suggestion you gave with the table-value parameters, but you never explained how to populate the table unless you use a DataTable. What if all I have access to is a comma separated list of ids in a string?